# testing bit=1 with shift operator and & with what I am testing against

Tags: c

I have a simple code that I assign 1 to index 1 from right value 1 and testing with shift and & operator. But it does  not seems to be working

In below code this line assign 1 to `...0010`  `x=x|(1<<1);` and this line test if binary 1 is present at index 1 form position right `if((x & (1<<1))==1)` but I am getting else printed in if. It should printed `printf(" 1 is present\n");`

Why is it the case, My assigning seems fine how to to testing bits at specific index, Please tell

```
int main()
{
    char *remote="192.168.10.15";
    char sbuf[1024]={0};
    //main_1(sbuf,remote);
    int x=0;
    //x=x|(1<<0);
    //printf("x= %x\n",x);
    x=x|(1<<1);
    printf("x= %x\n",x);
    x=x|(1<<2);
    printf("x= %x\n",x);
    if((x & (1<<1))==1)
    printf(" 1 is present\n");  
    else
    printf(" 1 is not present\n");

    return 0;
    

}
```

Comment: `if((x & (1<<1))==(1<<1))` perhaps?

Comment: Your `if` statement is the same as `if ((x & 2) == 1)` which can never be true. `x & 2` is either 2 or 0, depending on whether the bit is set or not, respectively.

Comment: You would normally write `if (x & (1<<1)) printf("1 is present);`.  You should not test whether `x & (1<<1)` *equals* 1, but rather simply whether it is nonzero.

Comment: To make things crystal clear, your condition should be `((x & (1 << 1)) != 0)`.